# Can I write into Windows Event Log from a Windows Scripting Language like JScript?

Tags: javascript, event-log

I have a small JScript code that needs to output its error messages. It is running from a Windows Scripting Host (as a .js file). I was wondering if it's possible to write into the Windows Event Log from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog](http://nzbart.blogspot.com/2011/01/logging-to-windows-event-log-using.html) does it this way:

```
function Log(message) {
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
    shell.Exec('eventcreate /id 1 /l [LOG] /SO [SOURCE] /T ERROR /D "' + String(message).replace('"', '""') + '"')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul. One other way is to use LogEvent method of the WScript.Shell object:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4ce6by3%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
It is less flexible but it can be run from a non-admin script.

Answer (score 2):

You can log the event directly after by using WscriptShell object itself:

```
var oWSS = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
oWSS.LogEvent(1,"this is error"); 
oWSS.LogEvent(2,"this is warning"); 
oWSS.LogEvent(4,"this is Info");
```

Comment: but ActiveX is limited to IE Browsers only